# What can be better to have : more Colums with Null or More tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am making a web app for Property management.
We have 3 kinds of Colections(actions) of rent.

Move ins

```
--------------------------
id
id_room
colect_date
rent
late_fee
other_fee
bookind_fee
Deposit
Hold Deposit
-------------------------
```

Rent Colections

```
--------------------------
id
id_room
colect_date
rent
late_fee
other_fee
-------------------------
```

Move outs

```
--------------------------
id
id_room
colect_date
move_out_date
rent
late_fee
other_fee
maintenance_fee
break_fee
-------------------------
```

Mostly Users can check them separately, but they can also be seen all at once.

1. So if i put them all in 1 Table, then with 1 query i can select all of them, which is better for performance, but the issue is that in Move Ins table we have some columns that are not in the other 2 tables. It's the same for the Move outs table .

For every ROOM we have, we do 1 move in, 3-12 Rent Collections and 1 move Out.
So we will have Many NULL values, if i put all the data in 1 table.
Example: Below all are included in 1 table. For every Room, we will have 3-12 Rent Colections, which means that we will have 12 rows with NUll values for (move_out_date,bookind_fee,deposit,hold deposit,maintenance fee,break fee)

```
--------------------------
id
id_room
colect_date
move_out_date
rent
late_fee
other_fee
bookind_fee
Deposit
Hold Deposit
maintenance_fee
break_fee
type_of_colection
-------------------------
```

2. If i split them in different tables, then to select them i need 3 Queries, or Join them, which is slower.

So my question is, what is better, to Split them in different tables OR have 1 table with a lot of NULL fields, at least 5-6 column fields will be Nulls.

**P.S: Every month there will be:**

```
 600-700 Rent Colections
 10-100 Move ins
 10-100 Move outs
```

Comment: I would probably do 2 tables, Move ins/outs and Rent Collections, and prevent duplicate data between the tables.

Comment: The best choice in terms of design is many tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned "1 move in, and 3-12 Rent Colections, an 1 move Out" it seems that separate tables would be better. This way you can eliminate duplicate data, prevent null values, and in general your tables would be better structured. You could have move-in and move-out both in 1 single table as both are single entries and monthly rental collections in another table.

Comment: & @Sean thnx for your answers, in terms of design i agree as its better structured and we can avoid the NULL's, but do you think is good in terms of performance as sometimes denormalization is better in performance.. Example when i will Query them at same time 2 tables ..  and the Tables will be with let say 100K Rows each, and it needs 2 loops in 2 tables to check the datas, instead of 1 big table.. thats what im consern will i have problems in performance.. (or tables up to 1M - 2M  rows will not be a problem)